# How can I add view below canvas in Android?

Tags: android, button, canvas

I have some canvas that contains text (in canvas) I want to add below this text a button.
I know that Canvas can't hold a button and I don't want to add the button to the canvas.

How can I add the button to the RelativeLayout below the text that I draw in canvas?

**EDIT:**

The canvas is not declared in any xml or layout
I have a class that extends RelativeLayout and I get the canvas from dispatchDraw function

Comment: I know this, but how can I reach the canvas to declare this?
I don't have the canvas declared in xml

Comment: I added an example of how to do this in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your canvas is contained in a view, so place the button below that view.

```
    android:layout_below="@+id/yourCanvasViewId"
```

Check out the [RelativeLayout developer guide.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html)

To do this in code, you could do something like this:

```
    int canvasViewId = 1;
    myCanvasView.setId(canvasViewId);

    Button button = new Button(this);
    button.setText("Button");

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    //set view to be laid out below canvas view
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, canvasViewId); 

    myRelativeLayout.addView(button, params);
```

Comment: I don't use views I use DynamicLayout

Comment: Your canvas itself is drawn in a view though.

Comment: OK but if im not mistaking this view is my relative layout
In this is a mistake how can I get the canvas view?

Comment: Just saw your edit. Without knowing anything about what you're doing, I would say that you're probably making things way too complicated by extending a layout then getting the canvas from it. If you do have a good reason to do this, then you'll have to just do the math to get the position of your text, then add a child to the relative layout and override onLayout so that it places that child under the text.

Comment: I found the position and and did this:

        removeView(mEndButton);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LayoutParams) mEndButton.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.topMargin = (int)textDrawer.getBestTextPosition()[2];
        mEndButton.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        addView(mEndButton);

Answer (score 0):

You can use the layout parameter `android:layout_above` in your layout XML file. Give each component an id and use `android:layout_above` or `android:layout_below` to do this. You could also do it in a `LinearLayout`